# problem with plot Directed graph in Matlab

Tags: matlab, graph

I have a directed graph (a road network). I tried to plot it and in some parts, the connection is via arc instead of two straight links (when nodes connected with 2 or more links). How can I fix it? [image]

Comment: Which function did you use to plot? Maybe you could also put a minimal example of 2 or 3 nodes into your question, demonstrating the problem.

Comment: I used Plot with 'Xdata' and 'Ydata'. I think it happens when the number of nodes are huge. This network has 12000 nodes.

Comment: Okay, you are using `graph.plot`. There curved arrows are default and have nothing to do with the number of nodes. Minimal example: `plot(digraph([1 2], [2 1]))`. Don't have an answer right now, leaving this here so others have an example to look at.